# Query not working with adding where clause after case statement on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have following query which is not working with WHERE clause.Any help will be appreciated.

```
UPDATE abc SET
col1 = CASE
WHEN a1_date < now() THEN "xyz"
END,
col2 = CASE
WHEN a2_date < now() THEN "xyz"
END,
col3 = CASE
WHEN a3_date < now() THEN "xyz"
END

WHERE a1_date != NULL AND a2_date != NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `WHERE` clause to use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
WHERE a1_date IS NOT NULL AND a2_date IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Therefore your comparison check right now will not work as intended.

> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators